# Given vector of function plot each of them separately?

Tags: plotting, vector

At the moment, I am trying to plot a vector of functions which consists of the change along $x$, $y$, and $z$.

Is it possible in *Mathematica* to give a vector of functions and plot them **separately** instead of plotting them all in the same plot (plotting them together causes the axes to get messed up)?

Comment: Something like: `lst = { < list of functions that depend on x > }; GraphicsColumn@Table[Plot[lst[[kk]], {x, 0, 1}], {kk, Length@lst}]`?

Comment: `GraphicsColumn[Plot[#, {x, 0, 1}] & /@ lst]`